# css style print to top left

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[image]

I need to move that qr code to top left, any idea how?

right now, the styling for that output is:

```
        @media print {
        body * {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #printqr, #printqr * {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        #printqr {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
        }
```

Comment: `position: fixed` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I hope that will solve your problem

```
#printqr {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }
```

Read this if you need more details: https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

Answer (score 0):

```css
parentSelectorOf#printqr{
  position: relative;
}
#printqr {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }
```